# Cannot bind to Dependency Property of type Point[]

Tags: c#, binding, dependency-properties

I have a dependency property defined in the code behind of a User Control like so:

```
public partial class StockControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty;

    static StockControl()
    {
        FrameworkPropertyMetadata md = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DataPropertyChanged);
        DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(Point[]), typeof(StockControl), md);
    }    

    public StockControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static void DataPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public Point[] Data
    {
        get { return (Point[])GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I am trying to bind an entire array of points to this dependency property in my XAML. However, the Data property is not showing up in intellisense. If I switch the data type from Point[] to a list collection of type Point, then it works.

I do not want to use collections. Is there a way I can make this work with a primitive Point[] type? I have read that Properties should not return arrays because they are mutable, and may be tampered with. Is this why it is not working?

Comment: You say it's not showing up in the intellisence, but does it build? I wouldn't take the xaml intellisence as always correct.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried your code and it builds for me with an Array of points dp fine.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array Type="Point" x:Key="myPoints">
         <Point X="50" Y="50"></Point>
    </x:Array>
 </Window.Resources>


<local:StockControl Data="{StaticResource myPoints}">

</local:StockControl>
```